# Iterate through json response

Tags: python, json, lambda, get

I'm trying to iterate through a json response, method is get.

this is the json

```
{
    "snapshots" : [ 
        {"snapshot" : "First"},
        {"snapshot" : "Second"}
    ]
}
```

I would like to know if any of you have an easy way to iterate through this and get the value of "snapshot" key, with python 3.X
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example

```py
import json

var= """
{
 "snapshots" : [
 {
 "snapshot" : "First"},
 {
 "snapshot" : "Second"}

 ]
 }

 """

data = json.loads(var)

for snapshot in data["snapshots"]:
        print(f'Value :{snapshot["snapshot"]}')
```

The output that i got :

```
Value :First
Value :Second
```

Comment: omg, I can see that my issue was that I was using simple quotes instead of double quotes, thank you Nabil

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = {
    "snapshots" : [ 
    {
    "snapshot" : "First"
    },
    {
    "snapshot" : "Second"
    }]
    }

for snapshot in obj['snapshots']:
    print(snapshot['snapshot'])
```